How to solve the R shiny error "argument is of length zero"
I have tried to run a function in R shiny. But I am getting the 'argument is of length zero' error. But the same function is running in R Studio without any error. Since my function is big, I will mention only a small portion here.
The source code is,
test <- function(X, Y, Z, filter_type, ...) {
  type <- NULL
  # Step 1: sorted_otu_md_func
  colnames(X)[1] <- "OTU ID"
  colnames(Y)[1] <- "OTU ID"
  id.common <- fastmatch::fmatch(Y[, 1][[1]], X[, 1][[1]])
  common_otu_ids_table1 <- X[id.common, ]
  common_otu_ids_table <- common_otu_ids_table1[, -1]
  common_otu_ids_table <- as.data.frame(common_otu_ids_table)
  arab_md <- as.data.frame(Z[, 1])
  colnames(arab_md) <- "Sample"
  id.com.md <- fastmatch::fmatch(arab_md[, 1], colnames(common_otu_ids_table))
  id.col <- stats::na.omit(id.com.md)
  final_X <- common_otu_ids_table[, id.col]
  final_X_with_row <- cbind(common_otu_ids_table1[, 1], final_X)
  colnames(final_X_with_row)[1] <- "OTU ID"
  # Add an "id" column to the Y using the OTU IDs
  #Y$id <- rownames(Y)
  id.md <- which(!is.na(id.com.md))
  filtered_arab_md_old <- Z[id.md, ]
  
  # Step 2: filtered_non_zero_otu
  row_sums <- rowSums(final_X_with_row[,-1])
  non_zero <- row_sums != 0
  filtered_otu_tab <- final_X_with_row[non_zero, ]
  
  # Step 3: filter_function
  selected_otus <- NULL
  if (filter_type == "filter_type_1") {
    # Check if the required arguments are provided
    if (!("min_count" %in% names(list(...))) ||
        !("prop" %in% names(list(...))) ||
        !("min_total_count" %in% names(list(...)))) {
      stop("For 'filter_type_1', please provide values for 'min_count', 'prop', and 'min_total_count' parameters.")
    }
    
    # Retrieve values of arguments from the list
    min_count <- list(...)["min_count"]
    prop <- list(...)["prop"]
    min_total_count <- list(...)["min_total_count"]
    
    # Check if any of the required arguments is NULL
    if (is.null(min_count) || is.null(prop) || is.null(min_total_count)) {
      stop("For 'filter_type_1', please provide values for 'min_count', 'prop', and 'min_total_count' parameters.")
    }
    
    filter_type_1<- function(x, min_count, prop, min_total_count) {
      # Function 'abundance_fun1' logic here
      id1 <- which(x >= min_count)
      pr1 <- length(id1) / length(x)
      sel1 <- ifelse(pr1 >= prop, 1, 0)
      sel2 <- ifelse(sum(x) >= min_total_count, 1, 0)
      sel <- sel1 & sel2
      return(sel)
    }
    
    sel.ind_abundance <- apply(selected_otus_occupancy[, -1], 1, abundance_fun1,
                               min_count = list(...)$min_count,
                               prop = list(...)$prop,
                               min_total_count = list(...)$min_total_count)
    selected_otus_abundance <- selected_otus_occupancy[sel.ind_abundance, ]
    
    selected_otus <- selected_otus_abundance
  }
  # Second filter type
  else if (filter_type == "filter_type_2"){"filter_type_2 function will run"}
  
  #Likewise third filter type
  else if (filter_type == "filter_type_3"){"filter_type_3 function will run"}
  
  else {
    stop("Invalid 'filter_type' argument. Please provide filter type.")
  }
  
  # Step 4: normalize_data
  rarefaction_depth <- min(colSums(selected_otus[,-1]))
  rarefied_table <- vegan::rrarefy(selected_otus[,-1], sample = rarefaction_depth)
  rarefied_table_1 <- cbind(selected_otus[, 1, drop = FALSE], rarefied_table)
  colnames(rarefied_table_1) <- colnames(selected_otus)
  selected_otus_1 <- rarefied_table_1
  
  
  # Return the final results as a list
  return(selected_otus_1)
  
}

where X, Y and Z are input files. Inside the 'test' function, I have mentioned three filter types and for each filter type, the function will run differently.
It seems like the error occured because of the above 'if else' commands.
The shiny app code is,
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

source("source_code1.R")

ui <- navbarPage(
  theme = shinytheme("simplex"),
  title = strong("test", style = "color:blue ; font-size:150%"),
  tabPanel(
    title = strong("Inputs"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        width = 3,
        fileInput("file1", label = h4(strong("Choose the X")), accept = c(".xlsx/xls", ".xls", ".xlsx")),
        br(),
        fileInput("file2", label = h4(strong("Choose the Y")), accept = c(".xlsx/xls", ".xls", ".xlsx")),
        br(),
        fileInput("file3", label = h4(strong("Choose the Z")), accept = c(".xlsx/xls", ".xls", ".xlsx")),
        br(),
        actionButton("btn_input", "Submit")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Selected X:", dataTableOutput("input_X")),
          tabPanel("Selected Y:", dataTableOutput("input_Y")),
          tabPanel("Selected Z:", dataTableOutput("input_Z"))
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Results",
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        "filter_type_1",
        sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(
            width = 3,
            selectInput("method_fil_1", label = "Choose normalization method",
                        choices = c("rrarefy")),
            br(),
            numericInput("top_percentage_fil_1", "top_percentage", value = 10),
            br(),
            numericInput("min_count_fil_1", "min_count", value = 10),
            br(),
            numericInput("min_total_count_fil_1", "min_total_count", value = 40),
            br(),
            numericInput("prop_fil_1", "prop", value = 0.5),
            br(),
            actionButton("btn_fil_1", "Submit")
          ),
          mainPanel(
            navlistPanel(
              widths = c(3, 9),
              "Tables",
              tabPanel(
                "Result",
                dataTableOutput("result_fil_1"),
              )
            )
          )
        )
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "filter_type_2",
        sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(
            width = 3
          ),
          mainPanel(
            navlistPanel(
              widths = c(3, 9)
            )
          )
        )
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "filter_type_3",
        sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(
            width = 3
          ),
          mainPanel(
            navlistPanel(
              widths = c(3, 9)
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  X <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    dat <- readxl::read_excel(input$file1$datapath)
    X(dat)
  })
  
  output$input_X <- renderDataTable({
    X()
  })
  
  Y <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$file2, {
    dat <- readxl::read_excel(input$file2$datapath)
    Y(dat)
  })
  
  output$input_Y <- renderDataTable({
    Y()
  })
  
  Z <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$file3, {
    dat <- readxl::read_excel(input$file3$datapath)
    Z(dat)
  })
  
  output$input_Z <- renderDataTable({
    Z()
  })
  
  result_fil_1 <- reactive({
    req(input$btn_input)
    req(input$btn_fil_1)
    method <- isolate(input$method_fil_1)
    min_count <- isolate(input$min_count_fil_1)
    min_total_count <- isolate(input$min_total_count_fil_1)
    prop <- isolate(input$prop_fil_1)
    top_percentage <- isolate(input$top_percentage_fil_1)
    
    result_fil_1 <- test(X(), Y(), Z(),
                                  filter_type = input$filter_type, method = input$method_fil_1,
                                  min_count = input$min_count_fil_1, min_total_count = input$min_total_count_fil_1,
                                  prop = input$prop_fil_1, top_percentage = input$top_percentage_fil_1)
    return(result_fil_1)
    
  })
  
  output$result_fil_1 <- renderDataTable({
    result_fil_1()
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

The reproducible example of X is,
structure(list(`OTU ID` = structure(c("OTU_14834", "OTU_18567", 
"OTU_14402", "OTU_14822", "OTU_16757", "OTU_15154", "OTU_7054", 
"OTU_14839", "OTU_18954", "OTU_1196", "OTU_13797", "OTU_11245", 
"OTU_19511", "OTU_19706", "OTU_19108", "OTU_4555", "OTU_19383", 
"OTU_18240", "OTU_7386", "OTU_10942", "OTU_4035", "OTU_5475", 
"OTU_15151", "OTU_12650", "OTU_18588", "OTU_19937", "OTU_15877", 
"OTU_19673", "OTU_19482"), .match.hash = <pointer: 0x0000024508c22230>), 
    C21.Ct.5R.old.C1_26b = c(16, 156, 1, 90, 213, 123, 58, 124, 
    104, 26, 8, 31, 0, 58, 77, 1, 59, 143, 5, 1, 21, 44, 49, 
    83, 15, 1, 26, 9, 0), C21.Ct.5E.old.C1_26b = c(45, 20, 6, 
    0, 0, 7, 12, 5, 3, 8, 5, 0, 0, 10, 7, 2, 3, 6, 24, 2, 0, 
    0, 1, 7, 15, 11, 0, 8, 0), M21.Soil.9_2S.yng.M1_27b = c(12, 
    4, 6, 100, 0, 20, 5, 15, 28, 4, 0, 70, 3, 7, 22, 0, 22, 30, 
    2, 31, 7, 12, 9, 0, 6, 4, 20, 14, 34), C21.Soil.1S.old.C2_39a = c(5, 
    89, 0, 50, 226, 140, 36, 173, 68, 33, 0, 12, 0, 20, 13, 0, 
    35, 40, 4, 1, 10, 22, 21, 2, 10, 4, 26, 12, 0), C21.Soil.2S.old.C2_39a = c(17, 
    145, 5, 57, 218, 233, 75, 194, 48, 116, 2, 13, 0, 28, 13, 
    1, 34, 52, 15, 2, 12, 8, 44, 0, 22, 6, 51, 39, 0), C21.Soil.2_2S.old.C2_39a = c(5, 
    153, 4, 58, 232, 53, 41, 58, 58, 78, 2, 6, 0, 13, 13, 0, 
    21, 34, 5, 2, 16, 25, 39, 1, 12, 4, 15, 5, 0), C21.Soil.3S.old.C2_39a = c(26, 
    143, 10, 79, 218, 95, 53, 63, 73, 63, 5, 14, 1, 16, 15, 1, 
    33, 49, 18, 2, 15, 20, 42, 1, 31, 7, 27, 15, 0), C21.Soil.4S.old.C2_39a = c(10, 
    97, 5, 51, 94, 79, 31, 62, 26, 43, 7, 9, 1, 3, 12, 0, 25, 
    33, 15, 1, 14, 6, 37, 0, 19, 10, 16, 9, 0), C21.Soil.5S.old.C2_39a = c(13, 
    100, 6, 103, 184, 92, 66, 100, 57, 61, 3, 13, 0, 20, 27, 
    2, 36, 41, 5, 0, 12, 25, 40, 0, 34, 15, 22, 25, 1), C21.Soil.6S.old.C2_39a = c(3, 
    93, 10, 50, 329, 61, 26, 49, 108, 110, 3, 3, 0, 9, 12, 0, 
    11, 28, 7, 4, 7, 13, 33, 1, 10, 4, 9, 25, 0), C21.Soil.7S.old.C2_39a = c(10, 
    216, 4, 163, 159, 77, 56, 64, 82, 224, 4, 13, 1, 24, 28, 
    0, 26, 60, 3, 5, 12, 13, 41, 0, 34, 7, 25, 29, 0), C21.Soil.8S.old.C2_39a = c(7, 
    54, 4, 111, 214, 39, 26, 20, 65, 67, 2, 10, 0, 11, 12, 0, 
    25, 28, 4, 1, 3, 16, 21, 0, 6, 2, 9, 9, 0), C21.Soil.9S.old.C2_39a = c(8, 
    94, 0, 70, 152, 73, 43, 30, 46, 60, 1, 6, 0, 14, 16, 0, 23, 
    37, 7, 3, 6, 30, 39, 0, 19, 5, 25, 15, 1), M21.Col.1R.yng.M1_27b = c(9, 
    7, 15, 69, 4, 3, 7, 13, 49, 7, 7, 40, 11, 11, 33, 0, 36, 
    38, 6, 33, 7, 9, 15, 1, 8, 3, 28, 8, 79), C21.Ler.4R.old.C2_39b = c(15, 
    58, 10, 43, 157, 65, 15, 52, 91, 42, 20, 14, 151, 31, 24, 
    3, 20, 50, 4, 1, 18, 13, 8, 17, 7, 1, 11, 19, 0), C21.Ler.5R.old.C2_39b = c(18, 
    104, 3, 50, 112, 105, 40, 71, 69, 31, 11, 45, 1, 31, 60, 
    0, 40, 40, 3, 2, 14, 11, 21, 22, 19, 3, 20, 15, 0), C21.Ler.5_2R.old.C2_39b = c(36, 
    50, 4, 31, 51, 41, 30, 43, 41, 47, 11, 44, 0, 38, 44, 3, 
    28, 37, 1, 0, 15, 6, 17, 7, 4, 3, 17, 9, 0), C21.Ler.6R.old.C2_39b = c(15, 
    39, 2, 41, 160, 95, 31, 62, 81, 18, 8, 43, 0, 25, 16, 2, 
    18, 47, 4, 0, 8, 7, 25, 23, 11, 2, 19, 6, 0), C21.Ler.7R.old.C2_39b = c(13, 
    89, 2, 69, 69, 60, 9, 36, 28, 26, 26, 9, 2, 29, 61, 0, 29, 
    65, 3, 0, 44, 1, 23, 12, 10, 2, 9, 10, 0), C21.Ler.9R.old.C2_39b = c(28, 
    78, 1, 79, 158, 111, 32, 98, 68, 24, 24, 17, 63, 24, 31, 
    0, 20, 67, 6, 0, 11, 13, 29, 29, 14, 1, 8, 26, 2), C21.Ler.10R.old.C2_39b = c(2, 
    49, 2, 31, 109, 41, 16, 29, 49, 19, 0, 27, 4, 18, 11, 0, 
    18, 19, 3, 2, 10, 12, 15, 26, 6, 0, 4, 1, 0), C21.Mt.1R.old.C2_39b = c(16, 
    99, 3, 49, 95, 76, 38, 49, 43, 34, 1, 30, 0, 22, 15, 0, 23, 
    35, 5, 0, 13, 4, 27, 46, 13, 5, 24, 21, 1), C21.Mt.2R.old.C2_39b = c(20, 
    115, 5, 63, 120, 79, 34, 63, 62, 24, 5, 18, 6, 21, 27, 1, 
    23, 63, 7, 0, 36, 8, 21, 52, 16, 4, 5, 11, 1), M21.Col.2R.yng.M1_27b = c(26, 
    5, 3, 70, 2, 51, 37, 22, 15, 24, 3, 48, 13, 33, 19, 0, 16, 
    35, 1, 40, 6, 5, 8, 2, 1, 1, 43, 7, 63), C21.Mt.3R.old.C2_39b = c(21, 
    71, 9, 65, 113, 117, 58, 87, 77, 32, 4, 23, 0, 55, 27, 0, 
    35, 53, 6, 2, 12, 22, 27, 51, 17, 1, 26, 16, 0), C21.Mt.5R.old.C2_39b = c(13, 
    246, 2, 94, 152, 32, 23, 25, 53, 76, 9, 5, 2, 8, 24, 1, 15, 
    33, 0, 0, 13, 9, 34, 56, 16, 2, 21, 15, 7), C21.Mt.6R.old.C2_39b = c(45, 
    215, 10, 95, 67, 44, 31, 50, 30, 47, 50, 23, 1, 13, 40, 0, 
    25, 67, 2, 0, 9, 13, 57, 22, 34, 4, 36, 18, 1), C21.Mt.7R.old.C2_39b = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), C21.Mt.8R.old.C2_39b = c(10, 
    127, 0, 50, 75, 46, 26, 37, 37, 19, 6, 17, 0, 7, 13, 0, 15, 
    32, 5, 2, 4, 11, 20, 33, 18, 1, 11, 13, 0), C21.Mt.9R.old.C2_39b = c(33, 
    160, 5, 60, 62, 65, 38, 39, 35, 24, 3, 18, 0, 20, 28, 1, 
    20, 32, 6, 3, 16, 11, 18, 115, 30, 8, 29, 14, 1), C21.Mt.10R.old.C2_39b = c(10, 
    134, 0, 51, 89, 45, 27, 27, 42, 7, 0, 28, 4, 10, 11, 0, 19, 
    28, 3, 2, 17, 9, 23, 71, 10, 5, 10, 7, 1), C21.Oy.1R.old.C2_39b = c(27, 
    146, 6, 43, 94, 58, 58, 49, 47, 47, 3, 20, 1, 8, 40, 0, 21, 
    34, 3, 1, 14, 11, 25, 78, 21, 5, 35, 9, 3), C21.Oy.2R.old.C2_39b = c(16, 
    72, 1, 38, 125, 48, 51, 40, 55, 7, 0, 18, 0, 19, 12, 0, 28, 
    15, 7, 0, 9, 8, 33, 39, 15, 1, 28, 15, 1), C21.Oy.4R.old.C2_39b = c(18, 
    63, 0, 45, 115, 127, 43, 94, 55, 45, 4, 44, 0, 92, 41, 1, 
    34, 35, 5, 0, 12, 8, 30, 15, 14, 7, 30, 22, 0), M21.Col.3R.yng.M1_27b = c(2, 
    7, 2, 25, 0, 5, 3, 9, 10, 11, 2, 12, 6, 11, 15, 1, 6, 11, 
    0, 7, 7, 2, 6, 2, 1, 0, 17, 1, 38), C21.Oy.4_2R.old.C2_39b = c(19, 
    80, 3, 67, 78, 91, 28, 79, 58, 29, 8, 15, 0, 30, 50, 0, 33, 
    57, 7, 1, 19, 2, 16, 32, 11, 0, 21, 22, 1), C21.Oy.5R.old.C2_39b = c(13, 
    35, 2, 52, 133, 75, 18, 67, 71, 21, 3, 9, 0, 14, 16, 0, 19, 
    38, 4, 0, 6, 10, 15, 76, 13, 2, 8, 12, 0), C21.Oy.6R.old.C2_39b = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), C21.Oy.7R.old.C2_39b = c(31, 
    144, 4, 64, 98, 50, 33, 39, 47, 29, 4, 14, 0, 33, 42, 2, 
    18, 38, 5, 1, 9, 7, 24, 42, 24, 2, 26, 20, 0), C21.Oy.8R.old.C2_39b = c(25, 
    130, 3, 66, 51, 48, 39, 42, 14, 36, 5, 6, 0, 11, 23, 0, 21, 
    33, 7, 3, 16, 6, 22, 62, 13, 7, 25, 11, 0), C21.Oy.9R.old.C2_39b = c(21, 
    59, 4, 44, 51, 79, 27, 46, 41, 15, 8, 30, 0, 10, 11, 0, 30, 
    40, 3, 1, 18, 8, 27, 25, 7, 1, 15, 9, 0), C21.Oy.10R.old.C2_39b = c(7, 
    182, 2, 84, 177, 104, 31, 79, 54, 30, 7, 20, 2, 21, 26, 0, 
    47, 54, 9, 1, 24, 14, 20, 31, 12, 6, 26, 25, 2), C21.Sha.1R.old.C2_39b = c(31, 
    185, 10, 80, 111, 173, 59, 114, 41, 55, 7, 21, 0, 37, 27, 
    2, 28, 66, 6, 4, 20, 6, 64, 18, 27, 2, 32, 15, 0), C21.Sha.2R.old.C2_39b = c(33, 
    141, 4, 65, 100, 127, 32, 125, 49, 53, 5, 16, 3, 27, 19, 
    1, 27, 63, 6, 0, 40, 6, 57, 29, 15, 2, 23, 27, 0), C21.Sha.3R.old.C2_39b = c(31, 
    222, 1, 33, 68, 156, 30, 133, 30, 95, 17, 18, 1, 87, 77, 
    0, 25, 59, 5, 1, 73, 2, 55, 9, 13, 2, 10, 23, 0), M21.Col.4R.yng.M1_27b = c(4, 
    4, 3, 52, 4, 3, 0, 9, 48, 12, 1, 32, 7, 14, 6, 0, 11, 13, 
    1, 20, 11, 6, 9, 1, 1, 2, 26, 0, 81), C21.Sha.4R.old.C2_39b = c(38, 
    267, 3, 38, 144, 176, 29, 128, 74, 97, 24, 13, 2, 34, 53, 
    3, 29, 72, 4, 0, 64, 9, 90, 29, 19, 2, 11, 24, 0), C21.Sha.5R.old.C2_39b = c(22, 
    71, 2, 50, 166, 48, 32, 30, 85, 27, 4, 7, 0, 12, 16, 0, 9, 
    25, 11, 1, 3, 8, 39, 33, 25, 6, 14, 27, 1), C21.Sha.6R.old.C2_39b = c(71, 
    92, 4, 26, 108, 78, 29, 47, 68, 95, 32, 43, 1, 110, 103, 
    1, 46, 78, 5, 0, 31, 3, 50, 26, 22, 0, 14, 23, 4), C21.Sha.7R.old.C2_39b = c(23, 
    59, 5, 40, 125, 65, 39, 54, 71, 21, 52, 6, 7, 13, 51, 0, 
    12, 41, 1, 3, 15, 8, 32, 60, 23, 4, 27, 14, 1), C21.Sha.8R.old.C2_39b = c(39, 
    75, 6, 49, 84, 56, 28, 50, 55, 73, 13, 21, 3, 33, 56, 1, 
    37, 46, 9, 4, 10, 8, 36, 31, 52, 1, 28, 23, 0), C21.Sha.9R.old.C2_39b = c(13, 
    61, 1, 40, 131, 50, 25, 48, 58, 20, 5, 11, 0, 12, 18, 0, 
    16, 39, 2, 2, 7, 13, 14, 138, 10, 2, 8, 8, 0), C21.Sha.10R.old.C2_39b = c(11, 
    105, 1, 83, 192, 70, 21, 52, 106, 23, 2, 31, 0, 29, 13, 0, 
    26, 28, 13, 1, 7, 37, 22, 8, 13, 7, 14, 26, 1), C21.Sha.11R.old.C2_39b = c(42, 
    109, 22, 83, 138, 106, 52, 50, 75, 23, 29, 63, 1, 34, 63, 
    1, 37, 73, 4, 0, 47, 13, 32, 235, 34, 4, 6, 25, 1), C21.Tsu.4R.old.C2_39b = c(12, 
    95, 3, 100, 213, 103, 46, 63, 92, 43, 5, 40, 3, 55, 18, 2, 
    38, 49, 5, 5, 36, 41, 31, 192, 20, 5, 24, 27, 0), C21.Tsu.5R.old.C2_39b = c(23, 
    104, 6, 49, 80, 77, 29, 36, 54, 38, 3, 46, 30, 64, 50, 1, 
    40, 53, 7, 0, 40, 7, 40, 69, 15, 3, 9, 13, 1), M21.Col.5R.yng.M1_27b = c(8, 
    6, 5, 76, 0, 8, 9, 18, 32, 8, 0, 56, 7, 14, 23, 0, 20, 23, 
    0, 17, 10, 4, 5, 4, 2, 1, 41, 8, 69), C21.Tsu.7R.old.C2_39b = c(38, 
    74, 6, 48, 70, 63, 30, 34, 25, 56, 11, 16, 0, 24, 108, 3, 
    16, 47, 4, 2, 14, 7, 22, 27, 7, 1, 9, 23, 0), C21.Tsu.8R.old.C2_39b = c(10, 
    65, 2, 52, 168, 66, 44, 55, 68, 51, 7, 4, 2, 25, 17, 0, 24, 
    29, 1, 1, 14, 12, 29, 21, 24, 3, 13, 12, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -29L))

and Y is,
structure(list(`OTU ID` = c("OTU_14834", "OTU_18567", "OTU_14402", 
"OTU_14822", "OTU_16757", "OTU_15154", "OTU_7054", "OTU_14839", 
"OTU_18954", "OTU_1196", "OTU_13797", "OTU_11245", "OTU_19511", 
"OTU_19706", "OTU_19108", "OTU_4555", "OTU_19383", "OTU_18240", 
"OTU_7386", "OTU_10942", "OTU_4035", "OTU_5475", "OTU_15151", 
"OTU_12650", "OTU_18588", "OTU_19937", "OTU_15877", "OTU_19673", 
"OTU_19482"), Phylum = c("Actinobacteria", "Proteobacteria", 
"Actinobacteria", "Proteobacteria", "Bacteroidetes", "Proteobacteria", 
"Firmicutes", "Proteobacteria", "Bacteroidetes", "Proteobacteria", 
"Actinobacteria", "Proteobacteria", "Proteobacteria", "Proteobacteria", 
"Actinobacteria", "Actinobacteria", "Proteobacteria", "Proteobacteria", 
"Actinobacteria", "Actinobacteria", "Proteobacteria", "Bacteroidetes", 
"Actinobacteria", "Cyanobacteria", "Actinobacteria", "Actinobacteria", 
"Firmicutes", "Actinobacteria", "Bacteroidetes"), Class = c("Actinobacteria", 
"Betaproteobacteria", "Actinobacteria", "Betaproteobacteria", 
"Sphingobacteria", "Alphaproteobacteria", "Bacilli", "Alphaproteobacteria", 
"Sphingobacteria", "Betaproteobacteria", "Actinobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Betaproteobacteria", "Actinobacteria", 
"Actinobacteria", "Betaproteobacteria", "Alphaproteobacteria", 
"Actinobacteria", "Actinobacteria", "Betaproteobacteria", "Sphingobacteria", 
"Actinobacteria", "4C0d-2", "Actinobacteria", "Actinobacteria", 
"Bacilli", "Actinobacteria", "Flavobacteria"), Order = c("Actinomycetales", 
"Burkholderiales", "Actinomycetales", NA, "Sphingobacteriales", 
"Sphingomonadales", "Bacillales", "Sphingomonadales", "Sphingobacteriales", 
"Burkholderiales", "Actinomycetales", "Xanthomonadales", "Pseudomonadales", 
"Burkholderiales", "Actinomycetales", "Actinomycetales", "Burkholderiales", 
"Rhizobiales", "Actinomycetales", "Actinomycetales", "Burkholderiales", 
"Sphingobacteriales", "Actinomycetales", "SM1D11", "Actinomycetales", 
"Actinomycetales", "Bacillales", "Actinomycetales", "Flavobacteriales"
), Family = c("Streptomycetaceae", "Burkholderiaceae", "Streptomycetaceae", 
NA, NA, "Sphingomonadaceae", "Bacillaceae", "Sphingomonadaceae", 
NA, "Oxalobacteraceae", "Pseudonocardiaceae", "Xanthomonadaceae", 
"Pseudomonadaceae", "Oxalobacteraceae", "Mycobacteriaceae", "Streptomycetaceae", 
NA, "Bradyrhizobiaceae", "Micromonosporaceae", "Propionibacteriaceae", 
"Comamonadaceae", NA, "Micrococcaceae", NA, "Kineosporiaceae", 
"Micromonosporaceae", "Alicyclobacillaceae", "Nocardioidaceae", 
"Flavobacteriaceae")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -29L))

and Z is,
structure(list(Sample = c("M21.Soil.P1710P1705P12S.yng.Me2_47b", 
"C21.Soil.P472P51P7P3S.old.C1_32a", "C21.Soil.P46P2P3S.old.926FC1_27a", 
"M21.Soil.P66P21P2S.yng.804FSH1_27a", "M21.Soil.P71P26P2S.yng.926FSH1_27a", 
"M21.Soil.P76P31P2S.yng.SH1_27a", "M21.Soil.9_2S.yng.M1_27b", 
"M21.Soil.1S.yng.M1_27b", "M21.Soil.2S.yng.M1_27b", "M21.Soil.3S.yng.M1_27b", 
"M21.Soil.4S.yng.M1_27b", "M21.Soil.5S.yng.M1_27b", "M21.Soil.6S.yng.M1_27b", 
"M21.Soil.8S.yng.M1_27b", "M21.Soil.9S.yng.M1_27b", "M21.Soil.8_2S.yng.M1_27b", 
"C21.Soil.1S.old.C2_39a", "C21.Soil.2S.old.C2_39a", "C21.Soil.2_2S.old.C2_39a", 
"C21.Soil.3S.old.C2_39a", "C21.Soil.4S.old.C2_39a", "C21.Soil.5S.old.C2_39a", 
"C21.Soil.6S.old.C2_39a", "C21.Soil.7S.old.C2_39a", "C21.Soil.8S.old.C2_39a", 
"C21.Soil.9S.old.C2_39a", "C21.Soil.1S.yng.C2_40a", "C21.Soil.2S.yng.C2_40a", 
"C21.Soil.3S.yng.C2_40a", "C21.Soil.6S.yng.C2_40a", "C21.Soil.7S.yng.C2_40a", 
"C21.Soil.8S.yng.C2_40a", "C21.Soil.9S.yng.C2_40a", "C21.Soil.10S.yng.C2_40a", 
"M21.Soil.1S.yng.M2_44a", "M21.Soil.2S.yng.M2_44a", "M21.Soil.3S.yng.M2_44a", 
"M21.Soil.4S.yng.M2_44a", "M21.Soil.4_2S.yng.M2_44a", "M21.Soil.5S.yng.M2_44a", 
"M21.Soil.6S.yng.M2_44a", "M21.Soil.7S.yng.M2_44a", "M21.Soil.8S.yng.M2_44a", 
"M21.Soil.10S.yng.M2_44a", "M21.Soil.1S.old.M2_45a", "M21.Soil.2S.old.M2_45a", 
"M21.Soil.4S.old.M2_45a", "M21.Soil.5S.old.M2_45a", "M21.Soil.6S.old.M2_45a", 
"M21.Soil.7S.old.M2_45a", "M21.Soil.8_1S.old.M2_45a", "M21.Soil.8_2S.old.M2_45a", 
"M21.Soil.9S.old.M2_45a", "M21.Soil.10S.old.M2_45a", "M21.Soil.2S.yng.Me3_46b", 
"M21.Soil.5_2S.yng.Me3_46b", "M21.Soil.11S.yng.Me3_46b", "M21.Soil.12S.yng.Me3_46b", 
"M21.Soil.13S.yng.Me3_46b"), Soil.Type = c("M21", "C21", "C21", 
"M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", 
"M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "C21", "C21", "C21", "C21", "C21", 
"C21", "C21", "C21", "C21", "C21", "C21", "C21", "C21", "C21", 
"C21", "C21", "C21", "C21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", 
"M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", 
"M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", "M21", 
"M21", "M21"), Arabidopsis = c("Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", 
"Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", 
"Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", 
"Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", 
"Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", 
"Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", 
"Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", 
"Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil"), Treatment = c("S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S"), Developmental = c("yng", "old", 
"old", "yng", "yng", "yng", "yng", "yng", "yng", "yng", "yng", 
"yng", "yng", "yng", "yng", "yng", "old", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "yng", "yng", "yng", 
"yng", "yng", "yng", "yng", "yng", "yng", "yng", "yng", "yng", 
"yng", "yng", "yng", "yng", "yng", "yng", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "yng", "yng", 
"yng", "yng", "yng"), BiologicalOrExperimentalRep = c("Me2_47b", 
"C1_32a", "926FC1_27a", "804FSH1_27a", "926FSH1_27a", "SH1_27a", 
"M1_27b", "M1_27b", "M1_27b", "M1_27b", "M1_27b", "M1_27b", "M1_27b", 
"M1_27b", "M1_27b", "M1_27b", "C2_39a", "C2_39a", "C2_39a", "C2_39a", 
"C2_39a", "C2_39a", "C2_39a", "C2_39a", "C2_39a", "C2_39a", "C2_40a", 
"C2_40a", "C2_40a", "C2_40a", "C2_40a", "C2_40a", "C2_40a", "C2_40a", 
"M2_44a", "M2_44a", "M2_44a", "M2_44a", "M2_44a", "M2_44a", "M2_44a", 
"M2_44a", "M2_44a", "M2_44a", "M2_45a", "M2_45a", "M2_45a", "M2_45a", 
"M2_45a", "M2_45a", "M2_45a", "M2_45a", "M2_45a", "M2_45a", "Me3_46b", 
"Me3_46b", "Me3_46b", "Me3_46b", "Me3_46b")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -59L))

Please help me to rectify the error.

Provide a minimal, reproducible example.

Yes.. I have modified the question with complete information. Kindly check once

filter_type is not defined in UI.  Also, try to use req(X(),Y(),Z(),input$filter_type) in defining the reactive object result_fil_1.
